# How to remove underscore from beginning of string

Tags: javascript

I need to remove underscores from the beginning of a string(but only the beginning),

For example:

```
__Hello World
```

Should be converted to :

```
Hello World
```

But `Hello_World` should stay as `Hello_World`.

Tricky thing is I don't know how may underscores there could be 1,2 or 20.

Comment: What have tried so far?.You can do that in multiple ways here is using `while` loop
`let str = "__Hello World" while(str[0] === '_') str = str.slice(1)`

Comment: Have you tried anything?  There are multiple ways this can be accomplished, including using a loop or Regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a regex to [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). `/^_+/,` says find any number of `_` after at the beginning of the string:

```js
let  texts = ["__Hello World", "Hello_World", 'jello world_', '_Hello_World_', '___________Hello World']
let fixed = texts.map(t => t.replace(/^_+/, ''))
console.log(fixed)
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex is pretty suited for this task:

```js
let str = "__h_e_l_l_o__"

console.log(str.replace(/^_*/, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Method 01:

```
var str = '__Hello World';
str = str.replace(/^_*/, "");
```

Method 02:

```
var str = '__Hello World';
while(str.startsWith('_')){
    str = str.replace('_','');
}


console.log(str);
// Hello World
```